# MSBuild throws The SDK 'Microsoft.Build.NoTargets' specified could not be found

Tags: .net, msbuild, msbuild-14.0

I'm using .net 4.7.2 runtime and MSBuild 14.

I have imported these two targets into a project file

```
<Import Project="<path>\Sdk\Sdk.props" Sdk="Microsoft.Build.NoTargets" />

<Import Project="<path>\Sdk\Sdk.targets" Sdk="Microsoft.Build.NoTargets" />
```

Then consuming the Sdk in another project(this project is referenced from the above project file)

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.Build.NoTargets/3.0.4">
```

Question : I don't understand from where the Sdk is being called. Can we control the behavior where it should look for the Sdk?